# how to call function using angularjs ng-click on template that has render from controller of grails

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, grails, angular-ng

> how to call function using angularjs ng-click on template that has
>   render from controller of grails. i have try this. but jquery function
>   calling works well.. but ng-click() function not working..what wrong
>   with me.i am battling with this.

**My controller function:**

```
 $scope.editTasks = function(){
            console.log("uu");
        }
```

my template has rendered code inside  of table:

```
<button class="table-icon editIcon" ng-click="editTasks()" />
```

Comment: `$scope.editTasks` must be in the controller you are wrapping the button

Comment: <g:each in="${moveTaskRuleDefList}" status="i" var="ruleIns"> <tr style="cursor: pointer" ng-click="editTasks()"> <button class="table-icon editIcon" ng-click="editTasks()" /> <!-- onClick="editTask(${ruleIns?.id});" --> <button class="table-icon deleteIcon" onClick="deleteTask(${ruleIns?.id});"/> </td> </tr> </g:each>

Comment: i have call angularjs function using ng-click() inside grails code..

Answer (score 1):

You have to define a controller and wrap your button inside it:

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="theCtrl">
    <button class="table-icon editIcon" ng-click="editTasks()" /> 
</div>
```

JS:

```
app.controller('theCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.editTasks = function(){
         console.log("uu");
    }
});
```

Comment: <g:each in="${moveTaskRuleDefList}" status="i" var="ruleIns">
                           <tr style="cursor: pointer" ng-click="editTasks()">
                               
                                    <button class="table-icon editIcon" ng-click="editTasks()" />  
                                    <!--  onClick="editTask(${ruleIns?.id});" -->
                                    <button class="table-icon deleteIcon" onClick="deleteTask(${ruleIns?.id});"/>
                                  </td>
                            </tr>
                        </g:each>

Comment: Where is the ng-controller??

Comment: ng-controller is in index.gsp page. and the template page has render into index page while click on edit button..the template page has ng-click function..